# Symfony- jQuery To Get id of the Particular input tag

Tags: jquery, html, symfony

Though am new to symfony framework, am struck with the simple work to fetch some id

This is my view Code

```
<?php echo $form['initialRows'][$num]['projectActivityName']->renderError() ?>
            <?php echo $form['initialRows'][$num]['projectActivityName']->render(array("class" => "projectActivity")); ?>
            <?php echo $form['initialRows'][$num]['projectActivityId'] ?>
```

This is my corresponding jQuery script

```
$('.project.ac_input').each(function(){
            element = $(this);
            projectId = $(element).val();
            projectId_array.push(projectId);
        });
```

What i need is, id of the Project, but am getting only the Project name any ideas???

Comment: is this a hidden field? `$form['initialRows'][$num]['projectActivityId']`

Comment: hey bagony, i dono is this hidden or not? am not able to track these things

Comment: try accessing the id like this: `var id = $('input[name*="projectActivityId"]').val();`